# Run mySQL on Server with Django

Tags: mysql, django, live, publish

I'm new to web development and I'm trying to go live with my website. Currently I can run MAMP mysql and then in the django app I can run 'python manage.py runserver' to run a virtual version on my system.

Currently I have uploaded (rsync) my django files to the server. How do I upload and run my mysql server on the web server? How do i dictate the domain? I know before that the domain was 127.0.0.1......

THanks

Comment: In 2012, [this programmer documented](http://tom.londondroids.com/2012/05/setting-up-django-with-mamp-on-mac-os-x-lion-in-steps/) running Django with MAMP on Mountain Lion and he notes "It's harder than you may expect" - anyways hope the link helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

127.0.0.1 is localhost, so if your code is hosted on a remote server you can still access the db with that host. You need to first make sure MySQL is installed on the server. Once that has been taken care of use the MySQL terminal to create your db, its as easy as that.

Here is a useful page of MySQL commands:

http://www.pantz.org/software/mysql/mysqlcommands.html